# pgfplots Producing Incorrect Plot

Tags: pgfplots

Why is this not working properly:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[xmin = 0,xmax= 1,ylabel = $C_A/C_A^*$,xlabel=$z$]
            \foreach \x in {.01,.1,1,10}
                \addplot[domain=0:1] {1/(1+exp(\x^.5))*(exp(\x^.5)*exp(\x^.5*-x)+exp(\x^.5*x))};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Produces:

[image]

While it should produce:

[image]

I have tried to increase the samples in the `addplot` options to no avail.

Comment: you are using `x` and `\x` in the same equation which confuses it. change all instances of `\x` with something like `\myvar` and it works

Comment: @ArTourter Thanks, that works. But why so?

Comment: Just a suggestion - use parenthesis around every variable in an expression, as when the variable has a negative value, `-` sign may change the order of calculation. Example: `\x^2` is not the same as `(\x)^2 when x is negative. Correct me if I am wrong, but that was my impression from playing with pgfplot. See this: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/125896/37570

Answer (score 5, accepted):

pgfplots understands the macro and the character versions of the variables. From the manual

> What really goes on is a loop which assigns the current sample coordinate to the macro \x.
>
> pgfplots defines a math constant x which always has the same value as \x.
> In short: it is the same whether you write \x or just x inside of math expressions.

So that fixes the first problem but if you use this `foreach` loop for other variables in the options say to use as a color modifier etc. it still won't work. This is the common problem of having a macro within an `\addplot` command unexpanded such as this explanation : [How to node foreach value in math equation?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228098/how-to-node-foreach-value-in-math-equation)

Hence, it is a good practice to loop with `pgfplots`'s own loop macro as below(I would also use `sqrt(#1)` instead):

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[xmin = 0,xmax= 1,ylabel = $C_A/C_A^*$,xlabel=$z$]
    \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{.01,.1,1,10}{
      \addplot[domain=0:1]{1/(1+exp(#1^.5))*(exp(#1^.5)*exp(#1^.5*(-x))+exp(#1^.5*(x)))};
    }
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```